# Dropbox .NET SDK listFolderLongpoll always returns changes : true

Tags: .net, api, sdk, dropbox

I am trying to write some code using the Dropbox .NET SDK. My goal is related to the following scenario:

I have a Master folder shared with one person. That person occasionally makes changes to files in the Master folder. I have a collection of shared folders elsewhere, each folder being shared with a distinct individual. Each of the files in the Master folder need to be copied to the individual shared folders depending on who each folder is shared with. Given the following folder/file structure:

```
Master (folder)

Master/a.txt

Master/b.txt

A (folder)

B (folder)
```

a.txt needs to be copied from Master to A

b.txt needs to be copied from Master to B

Currently this copying is done manually. My goal is to automate this process. Here's what I'm stuck on:

`DropboxClient.Files.ListFolderLongpollAsync` always returns `true` even when there have been no changes. Additionally, when I call `DropboxClient.Files.ListFolderContinueAsync` per the documentation for `ListFolderLongpollResult.Changes` to get changed files the `Entries` property is empty. This is true even after I make a change to a file.

Here is my code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var task = Task.Run((Func<Task>)Program.Run);
        task.Wait();
    }

    static async Task Run()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var dbx = new Dropbox.Api.DropboxClient("<ACCESS_TOKEN>"))
            {
                var listFolderArg = new ListFolderArg("/master", true);

                var cursor = await dbx.Files.ListFolderAsync(listFolderArg);

                ListFolderLongpollArg listFolderLongPollArg = new ListFolderLongpollArg(cursor.Cursor, 30);

                var lp = await dbx.Files.ListFolderLongpollAsync(listFolderLongPollArg);

                if (lp.Changes)
                {
                    var res = await dbx.Files.ListFolderContinueAsync(new ListFolderContinueArg(cursor.Cursor));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried getting an initial cursor followed by a call to `ListFolderLongpollAsync` followed by a call to `ListFolderAsync` to get a new cursor followed by another call to `ListFolderLongpollAsync` thinking maybe I need to find out if there were changes between getting the first and second cursor but the results were the same.

What the heck am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The results of [`ListFolderAsync`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_Files_Routes_FilesUserRoutes_ListFolderAsync_1.htm), [`ListFolderContinueAsync`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_Files_Routes_FilesUserRoutes_ListFolderContinueAsync_1.htm), and [`ListFolderLongpollAsync`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_Files_Routes_FilesUserRoutes_ListFolderLongpollAsync_1.htm) all depend on the `cursor` value that you supply. In order for [`ListFolderLongpollAsync`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_Files_Routes_FilesUserRoutes_ListFolderLongpollAsync_1.htm) to report `changes: false`, you need to supply a `cursor` for the up to date state. Your code doesn't show you storing the latest cursor though. You seem to be always/only using the cursor returned by [`ListFolderAsync`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_Files_Routes_FilesUserRoutes_ListFolderAsync_1.htm).

In order to get up to date with the latest state, you need to call [`ListFolderAsync`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_Files_Routes_FilesUserRoutes_ListFolderAsync_1.htm) and [`ListFolderContinueAsync`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_Files_Routes_FilesUserRoutes_ListFolderContinueAsync_1.htm), possibly repeatedly, using the last returned `cursor` each time, until [`ListFolderResult.HasMore`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/P_Dropbox_Api_Files_ListFolderResult_HasMore.htm) is `false`. The documentation has more information on processing these entries.

By the way, I redacted it from your post, but for the sake of security, you should disable that access token, since you posted it publicly. You can do so by revoking access to the app entirely, if the access token is for your account, using [the account security page](https://www.dropbox.com/account/security).

Or, you can disable just this access token using the API, e.g., via [`TokenRevokeAsync`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_Auth_Routes_AuthUserRoutes_TokenRevokeAsync.htm).